# Can I create an instance of a socket before calling WSAStartup()?

Tags: c++, oop, winsock2, wsastartup

I am writing a class for TCP/IP Network client communication. In the class header I create a SOCKET member. The class also contains a method for calling WSAStartup and checking the version. The method to make a connection first calls WSAStartup and then initialises the SOCKET member calling the socket() function. See code below.
I am wondering if this is "correct", or if there is a better way.

The header file:

```
/*network.h*/
public class IPnetwork
{
private:
    WSADATA wsaData ;
    SOCKET hSocket ;
    sockaddr_in socketAddress ;
    static const int SERVER_PORT = 502 ;
    unsigned long int = serverIP ;

public:
    IPnetwork(char* serverIPaddress) ;
    bool Connect() ;
    bool Disconnect() ;
    ~IPnetwork() ;

private:
    bool startWinSock() ;
} ;
```

The source code:

```
/*network.cpp*/
IPnetwork::IPnetwork(char* serverIPaddress)
{
    serverIP = inet_addr(serverIPaddress) ;
}

bool IPnetwork::Connect()
{
     /* start winsock */
    if(!startWinSock())
    {
        return false ; /* winsock problem */
    }

    /* Create socket */
    if ((hSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP)) == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        return false ; /* could not create socket */
    }

    /* fill socket address structure */
    socketAddress.sin_family = AFINET ;
    socketAddress.sin_port = htons(SERVER_PORT) ;
    socketAddress.sin_addr.S_un.S_addr = serverIP ;

    /* connect */
    if(connect(hSocket,reinterpret_cast<sockaddr*>(&socketAddress), sizeof(sockAddr))!=0)
    {
        return false ; /* could not connect*/
    }

    return true ;

}

bool IPnetwork::startWinSock()
{
    if(WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(REQ_WINSOCK_VER,0),&wsaData)==0)
    {
        /* Check if major version is at least REQ_WINSOCK_VER */
        if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) < REQ_WINSOCK_VER)
        {
            return false ; /* winsock started but version is too low */
        }
        else
        {
            return true ; /* winsock started with right version*/
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false ; /* winsock not started */
    }

}
```

Comment: It's `socket(...)` actually creating socket, and not supposed `SOCKET` type constructor. So you are fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're worried about defining a variable of type `SOCKET`, and when its constructor runs?

That's not a problem, since `SOCKET` is a C-compatible plain-old-data integral type that holds a socket identifier.  It isn't an object.  There's no non-trivial construction or destruction associated with the variable itself.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was worried about.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with @Ben that what you're doing is fine, I'd personally try to get this ugliness out of the mainline of your code. IMO, this is one of the rare times it's reasonable to create a global variable, in a header something like this:

```
#ifndef WS_INITIATOR_INC_
#define WS_INITIATOR_INC_

#include <winsock2.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#include <stdexcept>

struct bad_version : public std::logic_error {
    bad_version(std::string const &s) : logic_error(s) {}
};

struct winsock { 
    static const int version = 2;
    WSADATA wsaData;

    winsock() { 
        WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2),&wsaData);
        if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2)
            throw bad_version("Could not initialize WinSock 2.2");
    }
    ~winsock() { 
        WSACleanup();
    }
} ws_initiator;

#endif
```

Include this in your `main.cpp` (or whatever name you give to the file containing `main`), and it automates initializing/cleaning up sockets (as well as linking with the right library).

Comment: Is that safe for use in a library that "privately" uses winsockets and the main application may not know about it? {Think an inprocess COM+ component DLL}

Comment: @sehe: Yes, for that kind of situation it's a little trickier--you need to define an instance of the `winsock` object as a member of (for example) the `socket` class, rather than as a global variable. For example: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/46354/489

Comment: Mmm. I wasn't really wondering _where_ to initiate it, but rather whether it would be safe to initialize from a DLL or on ThreadAttach even if the main program might also be using WSA (looks like it as it seems to do refcount internally)

Comment: It does use a refcount internally, but no you can't safely call it (directly) in response to DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH.

Comment: @Pacerier: Other than "Microsoft says you should call it", I don't have a good answer to that.

Answer (score 2):

`WSAStartup()` must be called before `socket()` can be called, otherwise it will return a `WSANOTINITIALISED` error.

You can call `WSAStartup()` multiple times.  It is preferred to call `WSAStartup()` only once, but WinSock is reference counted so it can be called multiple times if needed.  You must make sure that you call `WSACleanup()` one time for each time that `WSAStartup()` succeeds, or else the reference count will be unbalanced.  For instance, you could call `WSAStartup()` in your constructor and call `WSACleanup()` in your destructor:

```
public class IPnetwork
{
private:
    WSADATA wsaData ;
    bool wsaInit;
    ...

public:
    IPnetwork(char* serverIPaddress) ;
    ~IPnetwork() ;
} ;
```

.

```
IPnetwork::IPnetwork(char* serverIPaddress)
{
    wsaInit = (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(REQ_WINSOCK_VER,0), &wsaData) == 0);
    ...
}

IPnetwork::~IPnetwork()
{
    if (wsaInit) WSACleanup();
}

bool IPnetwork::Connect()
{
    if (!wsaInit)
        return false ; /* winsock problem */
    ...
}
```

Though I would typically call them inside of a separate singleton class instead.

Comment: +1 for calling WSAStartup() in the constructor, then WSACleanup() in the destructor.